# Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant

Tags: java, h2

I Faced a little problem with a simple request H2 in test environment that is as follows:

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant ":localDateTime"
```

- 

```
String query="select * from Article E1 WHEN E1.date> " + "':localDateTime'" "

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, mapParameters(), Object.class);

private MapSqlParameterSource mapParameters() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("localDateTime", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().format(dtf1)), TIMESTAMP);

}
```

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: I think you meant `WHERE` instead of `WHEN` in your SQL statement.

Comment: @andrewJames thanks. It was a part of huge query with case ...when . I think the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the quotes around the named parameter.

```
+ "':localDateTime'"
```

should be

```
+ ":localDateTime"
```

JDBC prepared statement parameters are not recognized inside a literal.  So H2 sees a date literal that looks like `':localDateTime'` which is doesn't recognize as a valid date.

---

I cannot find a definitive reference for this (e.g. in the JDBC specs) but prepared statement parameters can only be used in the SQL where a (complete) SQL value is required; e.g. a expression or sub-expression.  You cannot use a parameter within a literal, or to parameterize a column name or table name.  And you cannot use one to inject an expression to be evaluated on the SQL server side.